# Android Wear NFC UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, nfc, wear-os

device Huawei Watch2 android7.0

when I called enableForegroundDispatch()

And my app crashed

Caused by->UnsupportedOperationException

When I use phone, that's ok, no crashes

How could I solve it?

Comment: Just by asking Huawei's customer service,they reply  the relevant interface has not been implemented yet,and are there any other ways to solve it?